# Reactjs TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I facing problem "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**" when i using `Grid` in elements.

the error i facing like this.

[image]

Here is my sample code.

> In this code only i am facing the issue when im using `Grid`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Card>
        <Edit {...props}>
          <SimpleForm>
            <Grid container spacing={1} align="center">
              <Grid item sm={6}>
                <ReferenceInput
                  source="appId"
                  reference="_apps"
                  allowEmpty
                  defaultValue={
                    props.location.data ? props.location.data.appId : ""
                  }
                  validate={required()}
                >
                  <SelectInput optionText="label" />
                </ReferenceInput>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={6}>
                <SelectInput
                  source="iconColor"
                  choices={[
                    { id: "primary", name: "primary" },
                    { id: "secondary", name: "secondary" },
                    { id: "action", name: "action" },
                    { id: "disabled", name: "disabled" },
                  ]}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={6}>
                <ReferenceManyField
                  label={"resources._fields.name"}
                  reference="_fields"
                  target="eid"
                >
                  <Datagrid>
                    <TextInput type="text" source="label" />
                    <TextInput type="text" source="component" />
                    <BooleanField source="showInList" />
                    <BooleanField source="showInFilter" />
                    <BooleanField source="showInCreate" />
                    <BooleanField source="showInEdit" />
                    <BooleanField source="showInShow" />
                    <EditButton />
                  </Datagrid>
                </ReferenceManyField>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={6}>
                <ReferenceManyField
                  label={"resources._triggers.name"}
                  reference="_triggers"
                  target="eid"
                >
                  <Datagrid>
                    <TextInput type="text" source="name" />
                    <BooleanField source="beforeInsert" />
                    <BooleanField source="afterInsert" />
                    <BooleanField source="beforeUpdate" />
                    <BooleanField source="afterUpdate" />
                    <BooleanField source="beforeDelete" />
                    <BooleanField source="afterDelete" />
                    <EditButton />
                  </Datagrid>
                </ReferenceManyField>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={6}>
               <AddTriggerButton />
               <AddFieldButton />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
      </Card>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

This is my actual code in that screenshot:

```
const TriggerButton = ({ children, to, ...props }) => {
  const CustomLink = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      React.forwardRef((linkProps, ref) => (
        <StyledLink ref={ref} to={to} {...linkProps} />
      )),
    [to]
  );

  return (
    <Button {...props} component={CustomLink}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default class AddTriggerButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      props: props,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TriggerButton
          component={Link}
          to={{
            pathname: "/_triggers/create",
            data: { eid: this.state.props.record.id },
          }}
          startIcon={<AddIcon />}
        >
          New Trigger
        </TriggerButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `field` is obviously undefined in your screenshot - so look into where it gets its value from. [Actually it's probably `this.state.props.record` that is undefined, sorry about that.] Your actual code sample appears to be unrelated (ie it doesn't include the code from the screenshot), so I can't say any more.

Comment: @RobinZigmond In this code only i'm using ```Grid```. if i use Grid here i am facing that issue. i just updated the actual code in that screenshot.

Comment: How to use `TriggerButton `?

Comment: @Viet Yeah sorry, i forgot to add. now i updated.

Comment: why do you put props on state ? instead of using the props directly ?  And as far as i can see you are not sending any props from parent to `<AddTriggerButton />` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't pass any props to `AddTriggerButton` so props is `{}`. So `this.state.props` is `{}` and `this.state.props.record` become `undefined`.

This is not good logic. You need to pass props and use `this.props` instead `this.state.props`

<AddTriggerButton record={{id: value}} />

Change `this.state.props.record.id` to `this.props.record.id`

Comment: If i change ```this.state.props.record.id``` to ```this.props.record.id``` and the same issue is comes.

Comment: <AddTriggerButton record={{id: value}} />

Comment: Yes i added sir, the error showed ```<AddTriggerButton record={{id: value}} />``` here only

Comment: @@ pass your value in it. I just show you a example

Answer (score -2):

Try to console.log(this.state.props.record.id) and shate here the reault. How you defined your the props? Maybe there is an asynchronous problem, so try to put '?' before the id like this:
this.state.props.record?.id